# JCAPS deployment to multiple external system environments

Tags: deployment, build, esb, jcaps

Hope a few people in here are familiar with JCAPS.
Coming from pure j2ee world, it is difficult to digest the deployment model that JCPAS offers.
While creating deployment profile, we need to map the resources (such as jdbc, webservice connector) to external systems. External systems are predefined with the target server ip, port, db name, credentials etc(in case of jdbc). So the problem is an EAR built for test environment can not be deployed to production environment.

In simpler applications we could store database/credentials etc on to property files and hence EAR built for UAT could be deployed to Production with out any change.

Is there a similar strategy available for JCAPS by which EARs built against an environment can be promoted to another seamlessly?

Comment: +1->solace for still having to suffer JCAPS

Comment: Hey! yes... product kind of sucks.. especially with the netbeans 6.1 IDE!! Did you find anything better yet? because soon Oracle is going to put JCAPS to rest

Comment: hey, what's wrong with JCAPS? I'm using it daily since 5 months, and find it quite conveniant for integration, except that it's closed source and NB 6.1 ...

Comment: @Kevin. my pet peeve is with NB6.1 and its over all performance during development/build.

Comment: @ring bearer. you're right for NB, I actually like JCAPS, but hate the Collaboration java editor/compiler!

Comment: I'm on a team of 8+ people - we abolutely HATE JCAPS. Has anyone else seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481475/jcaps-little-boxes-of-hell Man alive, what a PITA!

Comment: I think there needs to be a support group for this thing where we can all talk about our trauma and eat cookies :)

Comment: funny ! @javamonkey79 , I nearly hit my head against my monitor ( hm, gone are the CRT days, the LCD doesn't offer too much resistance) when the Java CAPS support told me th at an advertised feature of using LDAP to manage multi-environment deploy does not work properly on version 6.0

Comment: @ring bearer - Yeah, we've pretty much given up on getting much useful advice from them on JCAPS. We pretty much consider it a dead engine and are actively looking into moving to something else. Take a look at the <a href="http://www.eaipatterns.com/">EIP book</a> if you haven't already - it's a wonderful place to start for integration engineers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of research, I could find relevant info at:
 http://wikis.sun.com/download/attachments/38767325/JavaCAPS6+Application+Configuration.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1225463856000 and http://wikis.sun.com/display/JavaCAPS/Application+Configuration and http://wikis.sun.com/display/JavaCAPS/Application+Configuration+Lab.

Posting here just in case anyone stumbles up on this page as a search result.

Answer (score 2):

In JCAPS the Deployment Profile (DP) is still a generic layer;

1) as developper you configure your (dev) properties in the Connectivity Map (CM) and the Environment External Application (EA) inbound and outbound properties;

2) then you extract the configuration into a file :`asadmin extract-caps-application-configuration myear.ear`

3) and upload this file to your testing/prod Glassfish: `asadmin import-caps-configuration --host %HOST% --port %PORT% --user admin --passwordfile ...\passwordfile caps-config`

4) in `Glassfish\Common Task\CAPS\Env and CM Override` you adjust the properties according to the environment! (and restart the ear)

5) enjoy JCAPS efficiency *[optional]*

all this process is summarized in [Application Configuration - JCAPS 6](http://developers.sun.com/docs/javacaps/tutorials/demos/application-configuration/launch.html) screencast