# JCAPS little boxes of hell

Tags: netbeans, jcaps

Has anyone out there in SO land had to deal with this...when you go to build a new deployment profile in JCAPS, you have quite a few little boxes that you have to minimize before you can do the actual mapping (black boxes added to hide company specific info):
[image: horrible little boxes]

We've tried autohotkey and are looking into Sikuli - does anyone know of a good way to get around this silly UI design flaw?

Comment: I don't really understand what's your problem here, as far as I remember (I don't use JCAPS anymore since August), you've got to prepare a 'deployement profile' when you map 'logical resources' to 'physical resources', so if you've got alot of physical resources in your 'environment', you'll have alot of 'little boxes of hell' :) ... did I get something wrong?

Comment: @Kevin - nope you, got it right. In our case we have 100's of physical\logical resources - hence what you see here. I'll be posting a bounty on this eventually. Thanks for looking.

Comment: I'm not at all a JCAPS expert, but I would think that you've got too many resources in your environment, maybe you should split it?

Comment: That's an interesting idea - I don't know that we've considered splitting the logical environments. We have prod and test now, but we could feasibly have prod1, prod2, prod3, etc. I'll have to talk it over with my team. If this works out for us then you'll have to post as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a Netbeans plugin to take care of this. I can't publish the full source, but [here](http://monkeyingwithjava.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/closing-all-internal-frames/) is the main idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can build multiple environments that point to the same logical host. Just separate the resources into logical groups to make them more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you click on the "third" button in the deployment wizard that your logical hosts appear on the lower right. Other than that, the latest EAs you created are on the upper left.